# How to properly configure a Flutter app with Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I'm initializing the Firebase in my Dart code:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); // Initialization
}
```

but I get this warning in the console:

> 8.0.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.

Then I decided to add this code in `AppDelegate.m` file

```
[FIRApp configure];
```

but now I'm running in two errors:

> 8.0.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: 'Default app has already been configured.'

So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried hot restart

Comment: maybe `flutter clean` will works for you

Comment: I uninstalled the app and did a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the runApp function afterwards in the main function.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it was too obvious. I didn't write that but it was there in my code.